# How to align img and h4 vertically?

Tags: css

Is it possible to align this using CSS, so the text will be vertically centered next to image?

```
<div><img class="paragraph-icon" src="images/desc.png" /><h4>Description</h4></div>
```

Comment: what contain the class paragraph-icon ? did you try to add vertical-align: middle;

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css

Comment: @Haim Evgi: just background image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
<div style="height=IMAGE_HEIGHT; line-height:IMAGE_HEIGHT">  
    <img class="paragraph-icon" src="images/desc.png" />
    <h4 style="display: inline;">Description</h4>  
</div>`
```

replace IMAGE_HEIGHT with your image's height (and don't forget to add 'px;'), and that should make everything in that div centered vertically.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<div>
    <img class="paragraph-icon" src="images/desc.png" style="vertical-align: middle;">
    <h4 style="display: inline;">Description</h4>
</div>
```