# How do I vertical-align a span with an image that is floating to the right?

Tags: css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to do something very similar to the aligning text next to an image question: [Vertically align text next to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css)

The difference is, I want the image to float to the right, but it seems when I make it `float:right;`, the `vertical-align` that solved that problem doesn't work anymore? Is there a way to have the img float to the right AND have the text still middle aligned to it?

```
<div style="width:100px">   
   <span style="vertical-align:middle">Doesn't work.</span>
   <img style="vertical-align:middle;width:30px;height:30px;float:right">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Make the line-height the same as the image.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float: right` from the image. For the div, place `text-align: right`. It should solve the problem.

```
<div style="width:100px; text-align: right;">   
   <span style="vertical-align:middle;">Does work.</span>
   <img style="width:30px;height:30px; vertical-align: middle;">
</div>
```

Hope this helps. :)