# Creating Floated Image with text flowing around it with padding in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, invoice

Is it possible to create a Floated Image with text flowing around it in iTextSharp. I did the below and the image is not inserted but only the elements.

```
        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();//open the document
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(6);
        table.WidthPercentage = 80;
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;//80% centered

        Image imgLogo = Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/Images/image.png"));
        imgLogo.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        imgLogo.Alt = "Company has sent you a Invoice";
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(providerLogo);//added image to cell

        cell.PaddingLeft = 10;//left padding 10px
        cell.AddElement(new Phrase("Company Name"));
        cell.AddElement(new Paragraph("California"));
        cell.Colspan = 3;
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        table.AddCell(cell);//Added cell with image and text but no Image at all

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("INVOICE"));
        cell.Colspan = 3;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        doc.Add(table);
        doc.Close();//close the document
```

Could someone correct the code. What do i need to do to make image float around like in this link [Stackoveflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe a PdfPCell is either an Image or an element container.  HOWEVER, a chunk (within a phrase or paragraph) can itself be an image.

And there's also `myImage.setAlignment( Image.TEXTWRAP );`

I'd be shocked if that did anything other than wrap around the square borders of the image, but it's still far better than.

Note that this may not work when wrapped in a `PdfPTable`, as they do most of their own layout.

Comment: the version i use does not have the method. It's got a property `Alignment`

Comment: All the generic Java "get/set" methods in iText are properties in iTextSharp.  In this case: `myImage.Alignment = Image.TEXTWRAP;`

Comment: i still did not get this solved. Just because i hadn't recieved any answers from community i will mark this.

Comment: As I suspected, PdfPTable doesn't handle image text wrapping.  In order for that to work, it cannot be within a table.

Comment: thanks for that information. I did have that doubt since i tried directly adding wrapped image on document and also inside table.