# Aligning a image in text

Tags: html, css, alignment, image, vertical-alignment

When putting a `<img>` in text, it seems to want the bottom of the image to be at the text baseline, or a little above, example:
[image: example]

How can I have it so the image's center is at the text's center? I know it can be done with CSS, however I forgot how.

Comment: This is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `vertical-align: middle`. E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/8QzFV/

Answer (score 0):

Can you add padding to the top of the image?

```
#myImage
{
    padding-top:6px;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good way to try and solve this.  It won't work for one and even if it did it isn't maintainable.

Comment: @kasdega agreed this was my initial idea, I think @newtron answer is more suitable, i am voting it up.

Comment: agreed :) this question has been asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css

Answer (score 0):

just wrapp a div around it and use css style vertical-align:middle