# CSS Vertical align text to the middle of image

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I vertically align text next to an image with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css)

I have difficulties to center spans `vertically middle` in div.

This simple code: http://jsfiddle.net/4hDTb/

HTML:

```
<div class="bar">
    <span>Simple text</span>
    <img src="" class="img1" />
    <span>Another text</span>
    <img src="" class="img2" />
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.bar
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px black solid;
}
.img1
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px black solid;
}

.img2
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px black solid;

}
```

How to center `<span>s` in `div.bar` vertically middle?

​

Answer (score 17, accepted):

just add `img{vertical-align:middle}`. it's the image you would want to align, not the text.

Answer (score 1):

if you know the height of the container -- you can use `line-height` http://jsfiddle.net/4hDTb/3/  check the fiddle..