# Center elements within an image

Tags: html, css, image, center

I have tried the solutions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348889/css-vertical-align-text-to-the-middle-of-image), [here](http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/how-centre-align-text-or-content-vertically-css) and many other sources but I can't seem to get what I want.

I'm using Kickstart template and I want to have an image and text/elements centered (horizontally and vertically) on it. This is what I have:

```
<div class="grid">
<div class="col_12" style="margin-top:50px;" >
        <div class="mainImage"> 
            <h2>h2 Text</h2>
            <h3>h3 Text</h3>         
        </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.mainImage {
       height:400px;
       width:100%;
       background-image: url(img/Customers.png);
       text-decoration:line-through;
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
       align-items: center; /* align vertical */
 }
```

I have tried

> display: table-cell;
>   vertical-align: middle;

but these don't work.

Most solutions involve specifying a width. But I do not want to specify a width as I want the page to be responsive. If I use display:table it makes my background image smaller.

What I want is to:
1. Have an image in its own size
2. Have elements centered on it

Any suggestions I can try out?

Thank you.

Comment: What didn't work about the solutions listed? The is a very common question/solution

Comment: this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4WCr/) with your code works...

Comment: Thank you. I want the elements to be in separate lines. <br /> didn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue a while ago.
This is what I came up with:

**HTML**

```
<section id="abc">   
    <div class="table-cell">
        <div class="table-center">
            Centered
        </div>   
    </div> 
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#abc {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/nvH8nI3.jpg) 50% 0 repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    display: table;     
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #333;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #333;
}

.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.table-center {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 460px;
    background: rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.80);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 30px 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 2px #0F1519;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px 2px #0F1519;
}

.col-centered {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Js35/2/

Comment: Thanks Simon. But this involves specifying width. I do not want to that as I want it to be responsive. If I remove the width then the image resizes to the width of the table-center.

Comment: You can use media queries to do this.