# Aligning Image and Hyperlink

Tags: css

I have an image and a hyperlink inside a div, but for some reason, the hyperlink is not center aligned with the image.

Here's my CSS

```
    #loginb {
    margin-top: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    left: -438px;
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    display:block;    
}

#loginb img {
    padding-top: 10px;
}


#loginb a {
    color: #fff;   
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

and here's the html

```
 <div id="loginb">
                   <img src="icon.png" alt="login" />
                   <a href="">                  Login</a>
              </div>
```

Comment: Vertically or horizontally centered?

Comment: @SurrealDreams I think he/she means vertically centered :)

Comment: vertically - the center of the image and hyperlink need to match

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css

Comment: Thanks Jack for the link. Dunno who gave me a downvote. How naive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this, hope you will find your solution.

```
<div>
   <img style="width:50px;height:50px;vertical-align:middle" alt="vertical image">
   <span style="color:red;">Check it.</span>
</div>
```