# how to vertically align text next to a floated image?

Tags: css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I want to vertically align a span after a floated image.
I searched for it in stack overflow and find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css). but my image is floated.

```
<div>
    <img style="width:30px;height:30px; float:left">
    <span style="vertical-align:middle">Doesn't work.</span>
</div>
```

I give `vertical-align:middle` to image and nothing change!

Thanks

Comment: Well, it seems to change if you give `vertical-align:middle` to image. I tested it on Chrome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First remove `float` from it. Write like this:

```
<img style="width:30px;height:30px;vertical-align:middle" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-8.jpg">
    <span>Doesn't work.</span>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ws3Uf/

Comment: I use your approach and I remove my float from my image. But when I change `<span>` content to something that long 2 line, the second line goes to bottom of image
At last, I add `display:inline-block` to `<span>` and it works!
Thank you

Comment: @Mosijava - Using inline-block did not work for me - it just puts everything on the next line. Do you have an example of this working?

Comment: This won't have the same effect as `float` if the text is long enough to need multiple lines. http://jsfiddle.net/9667cqun/

Comment: This works for images on the left side, but will not work for images floated to  the right.

Comment: when you have a long text it breaks in a really stupid way

Answer (score 15):

Even though this is an extremely old post, you can achieve this using `Flexbox`:

```css
div {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img style="width:30px;height:30px;" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-8.jpg" />
<span>Doesn't work.</span>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/858fmucq/)

Comment: Flexbox wins again!

Answer (score 6):

Add `line-height` (equal to picture height):

```
<div>
    <img style="width:30px;height:30px; float:left">
    <span style="vertical-align:middle; line-height: 30px;">Works!</span>
</div>
```

[See example.](http://jsfiddle.net/FrQJF/3/)

Comment: What if the span have 2 line long?

Comment: @Mosijava--this solution only works for a single line of text. I'm glad sandeep's solution worked for you (you obviously did not need the `float` on the image like your title suggested).

Answer (score 1):

A `<span>` is an inline element, try adding `display:block` to the span, give it the same height as the image and a line height to match. Float it left as well. That should work

Answer (score 1):

You can manually change as well

```
<div>
    <img style="width:30px;height:30px float:left">
    <span style="float:left;padding-top:15px;">Will work.</span>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uW6QB/2/)

Or you can use a [table](http://jsfiddle.net/uW6QB/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
  div:after {
        content:"";
        clear:both;
        display:block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- float the picture
- set a height to picture.
- put a div1>div2>text after the picture.
- set div1 the same height as the picture.
- set div2 position relative, top 0 and transform translateY -50.

https://codepen.io/aungthihaaung/pen/ExXGvGy

```
.picture {
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}

.div1 {
  height: 300px;
}

.div2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="picture" />
  <div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
      <h1>Hi There!</h1>
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, deleniti
      perferendis! Ut, eaque iste incidunt atque perferendis odio laborum
      nobis obcaecati exercitationem molestiae nihil est recusandae
      mollitia. Fuga beatae inventore, adipisci ipsa aliquid corporis harum
      ex tenetur iure assumenda optio quod eaque omnis porro ab consequuntur
      unde a totam minima.
    </div>
  </div>
```