# How to align images and text in css?

Tags: html, css

I would like to align images and text accordingly.

I'm using the following code. Please show me how to do that.

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="icon-profile"></i> </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="icon-wallet"></i> Wallet</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="icon-signout"></i> Sign Out</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: create a demo with relevant code

Comment: can you add your code with in fiddle

Comment: use debugger option to see the style applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a fixed width for the icons then give it a `margin-right`, set `text-align: center` to make the icons center aligned.

```css
ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
a { text-decoration: none; }
i.fa {
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-user icon-profile"></i> Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-file icon-wallet"></i> Wallet</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-home icon-home"></i> Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-file icon-signout"></i> Sign Out</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to make the bullet points icons:

[Using Font Awesome icon for bullet points, with a single list item element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468359/using-font-awesome-icon-for-bullet-points-with-a-single-list-item-element)

https://www.sitepoint.com/use-webfont-icons-bullet-points-html5-lists/

http://techforluddites.com/replacing-list-bullets-with-images-using-css/

Otherwise if you're looking for specific alignment of two different elements:

[Vertically align text next to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image)

[how to vertically align text next to a floated image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516157/how-to-vertically-align-text-next-to-a-floated-image)

Hope these links help. Best of luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting like this:

In this code i am using [font awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)
More icon's library are available

1.https://material.io/icons/

2.http://www.w3schools.com/icons/

```css
ul{list-style:none;}
a{text-decoration: none;}
ul a i{
padding-left:10px;
  margin:0 20px auto;
  text-indent:2px;
  
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul>
            <li>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-user icon-profile"></i> profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""><i class=" fa fa-file icon-wallet"></i> Wallet</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""><i class=" fa fa-home icon-home"></i> Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-file icon-signout"></i> Sign Out</a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS vertical-align property solves it.

a { vertical-align: middle; }