# Image over padding

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an image next to a text inside a header but the image is over the padding.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0ufcLo5/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <img src="http://www.symbols.com/gi.php?type=1&id=3005" style="width: 50px; height: 50px">
    <h1 style="display: inline-block;">
      Hi!
    </h1>
  </header>
</body>
```

I need them to be vertically aligned together, and the image to stop being on top of the padding.

This is different than other examples here on stackoverflow because here Im working with paddings.

Comment: @DaniSpringer it's on jsfiddle..

Comment: You're missing the `;` after `width:95%`

Comment: @j08691 i fixed that, but the problem remains

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to vertically align text next to a floated image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516157/how-to-vertically-align-text-next-to-a-floated-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Flex` to make the text adjacent to the image:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
header {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.symbols.com/gi.php?type=1&id=3005" style="width: 50px; height: 50px">
  <h1>Hi!</h1>
</div>
```

Read more about Flex here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: yes, that worked! Thank you, i did not know about flex.

Comment: @Chormi No problem :) Flex is actually really cool. I will include a link in my post about it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this to you css file:

```
h1 {margin-top:10px;}
```

and add *"align=left"* to

```
<img src = "http://www.symbols.com/gi.php?type=1&id=3005" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" align="left">
```

Comment: Do not suggest style-based attributes such as `align`, as they are obsolete in HTML5.