# CSS - vertical align of imge and long text without tables

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

ok, I know there are a lot of questions here about this, that are supposed to be duplicates, but honestly ,I have read a lot of them, each with it´s specific case / markup - and I still can not get it right ...

I have a small image with potentially long text in a widget area. I need to make a center align, and when the text is higher than the image , to be still aligned to center (even if "higher" then the image) -

Fiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/as8xW/

I am searching for a universal solution cross browser and without tables

**EDIT I**

After the update of the answer - I stumbled and modified on a possible hack (jQuery)

What this script will do is actually wrap the problematic elements in table markup - thus transforming them to actual tables for IE ..

So assuming we have

```
.table     { display: table; }
.trow  { display: table-row; }
.tcell { display: table-cell; }
```

we do :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 7)
  {
    $(".tcell").wrap("<td />");
    $(".trow").wrap("<tr />");
    $(".table").wrapInner("<table />");
  }
});
```

Putting the above script with the solution provided by biziclop - makes it work for my tests ...

**Edit II**

@biziclop solution VR2 works perfectly, thus making my Edit I obsolete (or at least not necessary )

Comment: OP said in a comment in my deleted answer that the solution requires IE6/7 support.

Comment: OP also said this is OQ (cross-browser) - But thanks again for the effort and for trying :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I vertically align text next to an image with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**V1: using table-cell**

http://jsfiddle.net/as8xW/4/

To use `table-cell`, I had to put a wrapper `span` around `img`, because not even `table-cell`ing can change the image size to match the other cell.

```
li: table-row
  span: table-cell, vertical-align:middle
    img
  a:   table-cell, vertical-align:middle
```

**V2: using inline blocks, some fixed width, works with IE6**

http://jsfiddle.net/as8xW/10/

```
li: block: FIXED WIDTH
  span: inline block (with IE treatment)
    img
  a:    inline block with FIXED WIDTH not to drop below the image
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it looks much better  - in fact , I have tried this solution (or similar) before.. but A ) - yes , unfortunately I need ie6 and above , and B ) - even if your solution looks much better - the image is still aligned to the topof the title ( or the title to the top of the image) when the text is very long ..

Comment: Thanks for the update - It is still no-go for IE<8 . but see my update for a possible hack for those ...

Comment: Microsoft themselves don't even support IE6 any more. If only the rest of the world would let it die!

Comment: Added a second variation for old IEs. You can combine the two solution by using some css hacks (`*prop:`, `_prop:`, etc)

Comment: @JamWaffles I might agree with you on principle - but if you will look at browser statistics for CHINA http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser-CN-monthly-201105-201205 you will see that it is not the case . just to remind you - china is 20% of all world population.

Comment: Yeah, that's the real problem. If only everyone would realise how hard it is to develop for IE6. One can dream...

Comment: @biziclop (or should i say CSSMaster) - Thanks ! V2 is perfect ! (it also works with % width ..

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

html:

```
<div class="sidebar-box">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="left-col">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" height="50" width="50">
            </div>
            <div class="right-col">
                <a href="http://localhost/wp-sandbox/?p=283" title="Results Photography">
                    Results Photography Results Photography Results Photography Results Photography Results Photography Results Photography Results Photography Results Photography Results Photography 
                </a> 
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.sidebar-box {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
}

.sidebar-box img {
}

.sidebar-box li {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    zoom: 1;

}

.left-col {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    _float: left;
    *float: left;
    width: 65px;
    *margin-top: expression((parentNode.offsetHeight.offsetHeight/2)-(parseInt(this.offsetHeight)/2) <0 ? "0" :(parentNode.offsetHeight/2)-(parseInt(this.offsetHeight)/2) +'px');
}
.right-col {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    _float: left;
    *float: left;
    *margin-top: expression((parentNode.offsetHeight.offsetHeight/2)-(parseInt(this.offsetHeight)/2) <0 ? "0" :(parentNode.offsetHeight/2)-(parseInt(this.offsetHeight)/2) +'px'); 
}
```

fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/cKmQ9/ but it can bug in IE6 cause of fiddle, better try it on new document.