# Align text with an image

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I vertically align text next to an image with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css)

I am having trouble on aligning my texts and an image.

the texts and image are like

```
texts  ---------
      | image   |
       _________
```

I want the texts to be middle of the div instead of align to top.

I have:

```
<div id='test'> tests <img src='/images/logo.png'/> </div>
```

I have used the following css but still no luck

```
#test{
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

How do I align my text to the middle with image. Thanks so much!

Comment: place `vertical-align:middle` on the image

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `vertical-align:middle` should be on the image, not the container.