# CSS to vertically align text to middle of div

Tags: html, css

What is the correct way to force text in a div to vertically align to the middle?
I have found a couple 'tricks', but I need something that works with a single line and multiple lines. Hopefully I am missing something stupid simple:

http://jsfiddle.net/rogerguess/DawFy/

```
.header {
    display: inline-block;    
    text-align: center;
    width: 123px;
    background: green;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    height: 80px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<div >
    <div class="header">test1 </div>
    <div class="header">some text that will wrap</div>
    <div class="header">test3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DawFy/6/

Comment: Possible Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css

Comment: Thanks Clive, but unfortunately table cell jacks up everything around it for some reason. I posted only a small portion of what I am doing on the page.

Comment: kept playing with it.. and got table-cell to work. The issue was that table cell seems to ignore margins, so I added additional columns for the margins I wanted. Thanks

Comment: If you've provided an element with a display type of table, rather than allowing the browser to insert an anonymous one, you can use the `border-spacing` property (it goes on the table element, not the table-cell).  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-spacing

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change `display: inline-block;` to `display: table-cell;`

Comment: For the benefit of new readers of this answer, modern browsers now implement Flexbox very well. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 8):

If your multi-line elements need to wrap for responsive reasons, then your best bet is with Flexbox.  Due to the flakiness of Firefox's 2009 Flexbox implementation, it has to be handled slightly differently than you would do it for modern Flexbox implementations.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/mxuFa

```
<ul>
  <li>One lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li><!--
  --><li>Two</li><!--
  --><li>Three</li><!--
  --><li>Four</li><!--
  --><li>Five</li>
</ul>

li {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* fallback for non-Flexbox browsers */
  display: inline-block;
  /* Flexbox browsers */
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
  /* vertical centering for legacy, horizontal centering for modern */
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* modern Flexbox only */
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* legacy Flexbox only */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

Comment: All these Codes just to bring text in the Middle??... that's why I miss `<td valign="center"...` 
knowing that the `valign` is getting deprecated :(

Comment: It's a byproduct of browsers implementing rough Flexbox drafts where property names have not been finalized on top of everyone prefixing everything.  Realistically, all you *should* need is display, justify-content, and align-items.

Comment: I realize that it's a lot of code, but this answer is perfect. It uses newer properties while also covering legacy browsers. +1

Answer (score 2):

I've made a quick example for you, using display: table-cell property on the parent div.

```
CSS:
    .outer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

HTML:
`<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>`

http://jsfiddle.net/aKT42/

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will work.

```
    <div class="greenBorder" id="outer">
         <div id="middle">
             <div class="greenBorder" id="inner">
             Your Text Here
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Css Class

```
    #outer {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
        position: static;
    }

    div.greenBorder {
        background-color: #39B9FF;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }

    #middle[id] {
        display: table-cell;
        position: static;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #middle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/DawFy/16/

```
.header {

display: block;    
text-align: center;
    width: 123px;
background: green;
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
height: 80px;
margin:0px auto;


}
li
 {
list-style-type:none;

 }

<div >
<li>
<div class="header">test1 </div>
<li>
    <div class="header">some text that will wrap</div>
<li>
    <div class="header">test3</div>
```

Try this dont know if its "correct" but works

Answer (score 0):

Most of these solutions wouldn't work for me because either the height was manually specified (which I couldn't do) or things like inline-block and float would remove the ability for the an inner div to inherit the parent div's height.  I ended up creating a table with two columns each containing my divs and then I had no issues vertically centering text.