# How can I vertically align HTML text with the center of an image?

Tags: html, css, image, center

How can I make my image in the center of the image?

I have put red boxes where I'd like the text to go, as shown in this image:

[Img http://puu.sh/303Gs.jpg](http://puu.sh/303Gs.jpg)

[Here's my current code in a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DqHVs/1/)

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/ef/ef866067efc58dc49c7de0a39622eb5d7b6532bd_medium.jpg" />
<span class="target">
    <b> <a href="#"/>'Mouse'</a></b> - ' . Mouse . '<br />
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
span.target{
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: @user2417012 please paste your code here or use [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css

Comment: @user2417012: Please edit and reformat your question as it's not clear what problem you are facing.

Comment: Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/DqHVs/1/

Comment: @DivTiwari Its not my question.  Have you mentioned wrong username?

Comment: "vertical-align:middle;" on the image fixed it. Thanks for the help

Comment: @DivTiwari Please don't whore for votes. It's bad form.

Comment: @user2417012 I've edited your question into something close to what it should be. Take note of this in the future - your original post was of very poor quality

Comment: @Bojangles: please mind your language. I commented because many of my answers though they were correct and accepted by user are not marked as correct, may be because the users were new and not knowing the things like here. Anyways thanks for your comment i'll take it to account and +1 for your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use vertical-align

http://jsfiddle.net/hrvmG/3/

HTML

```
<p>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/64px-Smiley.svg.png" />
    Curabitur ligula non lectus.
</p>
<p>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/64px-Smiley.svg.png" />
    Curabitur ligula non lectus.
</p>
```

CSS

```
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IN CSS
=================
.comtent img
{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.comtent p
{
    height: 200px;
    width:200px;
    margin: 0;
        display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


IN HTML
==================
<div class="comtent">
    <img src="image/App_Sec2.jpg" alt=""/>
    <p>
        text to be sit in the middle
        text to be sit in the middle        
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `style="vertical-align:middle;"`  on Image and Text. You may need to set the line-height too.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
<img src=".gif" align="middle"> //The align attribute is deprecated in HTML 4, and is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead)


<img src=".gif" style="vertical-align:middle;"> //css
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.. make your html like this.

```
<img src="http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/ef/ef866067efc58dc49c7de0a39622eb5d7b6532bd_medium.jpg" />
<span class="target">
   <b> <a href="#">'Mouse'</a></b> - ' . Mouse . '<br />
</span>
```

make your css like this

```
span.target{
display:inline;
}
img{vertical-align:middle;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the size of the picture is constant, you could try:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="..." alt=""/>
    <p>
        text to be sit in the middle
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item img
{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
.item p
{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```