# Vertical alignment of text and a div inside another one

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

HTML

```html
<div id="divTop">divTop</div>
<div id="divBottom">divBottom
<div id="divCenter">divCenter</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
#divTop{
    height:50px;
    background:#008080;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#divBottom{
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:thick solid blue;
}
#divCenter{
    width:50vmin;
    height:50vmin;
   border:medium solid red;     
}
```

I want: 
 `divCenter` to be centered both horizontally and vertically inside `divBottom` and also  text inside all divs to be vertically centered.
Please, help.

jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bonaca/7JpJP/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi SunSky I forked your fiddle and made this one, you can use `transformation` properties to rotate the text. This should work in webkit browsers, mozilla, opera and IE9. I didn't try it on earlier versions of IE but it should work at least in IE versions 7 and 8. The `transform` property works with the browsers mentioned except <=IE8 for IE 7,8 I put css property `writing-mode:tb-lr;` and `text-orientation:sideways-lr;` to get the desired effect in these older IE browsers.  You will have to play with those values to get what you really want. With `transformations` it's easier since you only have to rotate it to the point you want it, if you want to center it or move it from the edges of the `divCenter` just use `paddings`, to center the box you use `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;` for these to work you need to have a `width` set you can use 100% here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FmUE/11/) so you can see the code, and also here's [W3 writing-mode documentation](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-writing-modes/#writing-mode). I hope this helps if you have any more questions or comments feel free to ask/comment.

**EDIT:**

I did not read the question carefully I will leave the info behind just as additional info on text transformations to create vertical text. To center vertical text you can check out thi link [It's about how to vertically align and how not do it](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/) the final examples are proably the one's you're looking for, if that does not work there's some questions on Stackoverflow that can help you here are the links:

[Vertically Align text in a Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div) Has some links to more information.

[How do I vertically align text next to an image with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css?rq=1) For this one check the second answer it's simple and gives some good tips and ways of archieveing what you want. I hope this helps and that this is what you really wanted. Here's the latests [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLf3g/3/) it should work like you want, what you have to do is set a `height` and `width` to center vertically then put 50% for the `top` property and then for the `margin-top` property put the negative half of the `height` of the `div` you want to center. If you need to apply this alignment to all `divs` just use the CSS properties in each corresponding `div` or for easier code create a **class** (`HTML <div class="foo"></div> CSS .foo{}`) with these properties and just add it to elements that you want the text vertically aligned.

Comment: Samuel, thanks for your efforts, especially about transformation features. But, you're probably missed some part of my post. I need the text inside all divs make vertically `centered`, not vertically `oriented`. It means horizontally placed, but top and bottom margin should be equal. Also the `center` div itself should be vertically centered inside its parent. Could you try, please ?

Comment: Oh you're right SunSky I will take a further look into it and post an aswer as soon as I can.

Comment: `divCenter` is not vertically centered in your jsfiddle, but I hope i will solve that using your links. Thanks a lot. Let's say - solved.

Comment: No problem I did a last modification on the jsfiddle if you want to check it out using another technique this one should be the one you need.