# Text Will NOT Vertically Align Inside Div No Matter What

Tags: html, css

inline-block, table-cell, line-height, etc. none of it affects the alignment of my text...

Demo: http://colechrzan.com/tv_rewrite

HTML:

```
<div class="toolbar">
    <form>
        <div class="search">
            <input type="text">
            <div class="remove">Clear</div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.remove {
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #1E1E20;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -16px;
    left: calc(50% + 15px);
    height: 32px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font: 18px 'Open Sans';
}
```

I've tested countless solutions and nothing matters; the alignment always remains as it looks now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I vertically align text next to an image with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css)

Comment: Why are you using a div instead of a button anyway? it's like using a bag as a hammer. Yes, completely nonsense.

Comment: because i was using a button but thought using a div might fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line-height: 32px` is the key here, but it's getting overridden by the font declaration below, so you could change that to:

```
font: 18px/32px 'Open Sans';
```