# GWT Label with HTML CSS For Text Padding

Tags: java, css, gwt

I have an HTML label in GWT

```
    Label L1 = new HTML("<span class=noMargin><img src=b0.png width=30 height=30></span><span class=legendText>$0 - $"+cutoffs.get(0)+"</span>");
    dock1.addNorth(L1,5);
```

What I want is for the image to display against the bottom of the label and the text to be centered vertically inside the label.  What ends up happening is that both the image and the text end up getting the bottom padding from the legendText css.  Here is the css in question.

```
.legendText{
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.noMargin{
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: why not use a horizontal panel, packing with center layout? this inline html looks dirty..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think having the HTML in GWT is effecting the alignment. See: [How do I vertically align text next to an image with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css)

i.e. add `style="vertical-align:middle"` to your img element.