# Align text next to image using css

Tags: html, css

How would I align my square image next to the menu text.

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sXSTg/4/)

I tried

```
vertical-align: middle
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I vertically align text next to an image with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `vertical-align:middle` to the `img` itself as opposed to the `li`.

**CSS**

```
#cssmenu ul li img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Working - [**jsFiddle here**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sXSTg/6/)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `vertical-align: middle;` to the IMG tag.  Works for me.

```
<li class='active'>
  <a href='#'>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Box_square.gif" 
      style="padding:10px; vertical-align: middle;" width="24" height="24">
    <span>Menu1</span>  
  </a>
</li>
```

Also, the height and width attributes don't need "px" units.