# Need span in middle of image but not working

Tags: html

I am trying bring text in middle regarding image but it's not working.

I tried this but not working either

[Vertically align text next to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css)

HTML

```
<div id="z" class="cz">
    <div id="a" class="ca"> 
        <img src="http://www.skateboardsofchoice.co.uk/assets/meta/130/130/1/blanks_88623933c05cc5bbb9d99ed2fe6a74e6.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="b" class="cb"> 
        <span id="spanID" class="someClass">Some Text</span>
        <img src="http://www.ucl.ac.uk/Library/Images/ml_big_go.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cz { 
    width:100%; 
    height: 30%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.ca { 
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 30px;
}

.cb { 
 position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    margin: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/frsA5/116/

Comment: give `vertical-align:middle` to image

Comment: the linked questions answers are correct. so is the answer left by Learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `vertical-align:middle` to both span and image.

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/frsA5/117/)

`Vertical-align` `img` will also work but for be on safer side align span vertically middle.

Comment: it's not exactly in middle of image :(

Comment: dude, its in the middle. which browser are you using?

Comment: yes it is. (text for limit)