# image and text not aligning in the middle?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to image and text in middle.

```
  <div class="topHeader">
    <img src="Images/loginheader.jpg" />
    <span> Sample text</span>                        
  </div>

div.topHeader {
   height:70px;
   background-color:#868686;
   font-family: Segoe UI;
   font-size:40px;
   padding-left:30px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FrR72/)

Comment: add text-align:center;

Comment: and remove padding-left, a little googling could of solved this... or a little css knowledge

Comment: I need padding left to move image and text little further

Comment: i am really bad at css and if you guys dont like this post. I will delete it.

Comment: hummmmmmm in the middle,... vertically or horizontally?

Comment: text-align:center did not worked

Comment: @James123 Since `<img>` and `<span>` are inline elements (replaced and non-replaced respectively) you could align them horizontally by using `text-align: center` to the parent element which is `.topHeader` as: http://jsfiddle.net/FrR72/5/

Comment: @SamotnyPocitac That’s just plain rude. Grow up.

Comment: and then use padding for the text

Comment: i dont want image and text center of the page. I want  both equal align. I mean now text showing bottom of the image.

Comment: @James123 But for vertical alignment you could use `div.topHeader img { vertical-align: middle; }` as: http://jsfiddle.net/FrR72/6/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I vertically align text next to an image with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css)

Answer (score 1):

Apply

`display:table;` to your container and `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;` to the span.

check this: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/FrR72/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `img{float:left}` and `div.topHeader{line-height:70px}`.

In fact, using `line-height` equal to the height of your div will center a one-lined text (and the image) vertically. Just don't forget to make your image to float in order to write text in the same line as the image.
A [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/FrR72/14/)