# How to add icon to a UL list tab

Tags: html, css, css-position

I created a JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Qw2Q7

HTML:

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li class="active">By Name</li>
    <li>By Specialty</li>
    <li>By Location</li>
</ul>
```

What I am looking to do is add an image on the left of the text of each tab, something like this:

[image]

How can I accomplish adding the icon to each tab like pictured above?

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qw2Q7/3/

Comment: The mouse over color doesn't change with that version. I tried it already :/

Comment: the question you asked do not mention that.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge The mouse-over color change seems to work just fine for me on Chrome/Win7

Comment: For the "active" menu.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge It doesn't change in the fiddle you provided either. Is this something you want to add? If so, you'll need to post another question about that specifically.

Comment: @DrydenLong My apology as I have mistakenly thought it did. works fine :) UPVOTED your response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Css `list-style-image` Property.

HTML

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li class="active person">By Name</li>
    <li class="book">By Specialty</li>
    <li class="target">By Location</li>
</ul>
```

then CSS

```
ul#tabs li.person {
list-style-image: url('images/person.png');
}

ul#tabs li.book {
list-style-image: url('images/book.png');
}

ul#tabs li.target {
list-style-image: url('images/target.png');
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Instead of the above way, which might take a little more altering you could just change the background of the li and the using `background-position` property:

HTML

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li class="active person">By Name</li>
    <li class="book">By Specialty</li>
    <li class="target">By Location</li>
</ul>
```

then CSS

```
ul#tabs li.person {
background: #3C75C3 url('images/person.png') no-repeat;
background-position: 7px center;
}

ul#tabs li.book {
background: #3C75C3 url('images/person.png') no-repeat;
background-position: 7px center;
}

ul#tabs li.target {
background: #3C75C3 url('images/person.png') no-repeat;
background-position: 7px center;
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Qw2Q7/57/

Comment: Looks very clean and simple. I will try it. I UPVOTED your answer for the time being.

Comment: Thanks! Also, if the images dont show up, you might want to use, `float: left/right` in your css instead of `display:inline`. If you want I can make the code in jsfiddle

Comment: If you can please... The image and the text I would like to center vertically and the a little padding between the text and the image.

Comment: I just made an update to my answer. It might be an easier solution with your code.

Comment: here is an example at JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qw2Q7/57/ .. Im using the same images for all three.. but the code is all there.

Comment: Think your is working. I will add it to my code and test... Thanks.

Comment: WOW... the placement of the lines in CSS makes a difference!!!. I think it's working. I will verify. Thanks :)

Comment: One more thing... I need to put spaces between icon and text.

Comment: Actually nevermind, I had to make the padding more and it's working fine now. Thanks :) ACCEPTED your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just use an `img` tag like so:

```
<li class="active"><img src="whatever.png" />By Name</li>
```

Comment: The image is not aligned properly vertically if I use it like that.

Comment: add css to it. I've updated ur fiddle and posted as a comment.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge That's another question then... See here for how to align the images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css

Comment: @ajc This solution works. But I think I might go with Kheema's as his uses the CSS method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `:before` pseudo element to put the icon in  every list item.

for example check the CSS below and the ***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qw2Q7/12/)***. and now update ***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qw2Q7/21/)***

```
li:before
    {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    content:url('http://lorempixel.com/20/20');
    left:0;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    }
li:before :hover
    {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    content:url('http://lorempixel.com/20/20');
    left:0;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    }
```

if you need separate icons then you have to add the class in each `li`. For example I've added class `.place`.

```
li.place:before
    {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    content:url('http://placehold.it/20/20');
    left:0;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    }
```

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge does this solution helpful for you?

Comment: the image is calling from the server .this might be reason image appear slightly later, but if you use your local images or icon it will run perfect.

Comment: What if I wanted three separate icon for three different tab?

Comment: I am updating my code to match yours and will update you. Thanks :)

Comment: How can I vertically align the icon and the text center? I updated my question with the image of how it's showing up.

Comment: you can use `vertical-align:top`

Comment: for the image or inside the LI:before?

Comment: what is your icon size?

Comment: They are 32X32 right now, but I might make them smaller

Comment: after seeing the screen the text appear a bit lower. so you have to play with margin-top or padding-top values in `li` only.

Comment: From your code the boxes became bigger maybe thats why. Is there any way to keep the box same size as my original fiddle and just insert the image? Sorry, but I am trying to make it close to being perfect :)

Comment: since you are going to use icons and ideal size is something around 20px/20px. lets use this values and see if its fit.

Comment: Used smaller the image but for some reason the text is still not aligned center vertically :/

Comment: okay if you need to move icon up or down work on `:before` element using `top` and `left`. or you need to play with text  then make changes on `li` by giving ` vertical-align' property. Hope it will help you.

Comment: @KheemaPandey... Thank you for the help. I think I will be using JCBiggar's solution as it's working perfectly. Yours worked as well but it created the buttons bigger. Thank you for the help. I UPVOTED your answer btw.

Answer (score 2):

You can define an **id** for each **li**, for example:

```
<li id="icon-name" class="active">By Name</li>
```

and then to define it a background (the icon) in your css, like:

```
#icon-name {
background: url('_IMAGE_PATH_') 10px center no-repeat;
padding-left: 20px;
}
```

I included padding so the text starts after the icon, and doesn't appear above it / cover it.

- "10px" - how far you want it from the left edge
- "center" - to have the icon/image in the middle of your **li**
- Since it's a background, you need also to prevent it from repeating, by "no repeat"

_IMAGE_PATH_ should be changed to the actual path of the image.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution. I will test it out. Thanks @dnns

Comment: Something else -- in order to keep your colour, you have already defined there, just include it (#3C75C3) before "no-repeat", for example.

Comment: Actually it's my mistake because mine wasn't changing color either. Sorry. I upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li class="active">
    <table cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 style=''>
    <tr><td><img src='source'></td><td>By Name</td></tr></table></li>
    <li>By Specialty</li>
    <li>By Location</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: really table required here?

Comment: Am trying to avoid using table... Thanks for the response

Comment: `tables` should only be used for "tabular data" in current spec.