# Align text with image

Tags: html, css

How can I **vertically** align text inside the `div` with the `image`?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C6pf7/3/

EDIT: I cannot use `display:table;` or `height` for `div1`

Comment: "Nice" trick to get around the requirement of including code in your question when you like to jsfiddle. Now try asking a proper question (you might want to explain what you mean by "align with the image").

Comment: add display:table; to #div1 in CSS

Comment: Dup; [Vertically Align text in a Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Comment: The question is better for your edit, but you haven't got the hang of *including code in the question* yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried putting the image as a background in the div that's one way of sort of doing it. Although you can use

```
vertical-align:middle
```

Heres a link to question already asked previously.

[Vertically align text next to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css)

Answer (score 1):

Use below Code:

```
<div id = "div1"  style='float:left;width:100%'>
<p align='left' >   
    <img src="http://www.loriswebs.com/html-tips/images/delphinium-close1c.jpg"
              id= "img1" style='float:left;'></img>    
    123
</p>

</div>
```

Comment: This is not for vertical align. The code is for Align text and image side by side. No downvotes pls!!

Answer (score 0):

Set `min-height:` for `#div`

Like

```
#div1{
   text-align: center;
    vertical-align : middle;
    border: 2px solid red;
    min-height:80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `line-height:75px` in your **css** and add a new `div` with `style="clear:both;"`

**Css:**

```
#div1{
       text-align: center;
        vertical-align : middle;
        border: 2px solid red;
        line-height: 75px;   /* Add this */
}
```

Updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6pf7/6/)**

Comment: It wasn't me downvoting