# How to vertical align an image and anchor thats withing a paragraph

Tags: css

I have a simple paragraph, image, and anchor in a list element like this:

```
<li>
 <p>
    <a href="/myprofile">
     <img src="MyPic.jpg"> Malcolm Gray</a>
     Here is comment made by me
     <a href="/delete">Delete</a>
 </p>
</li>
```

I have applied an `{align-vertical:middle}` to the image which has resulted in the image and the comment text aligned perfectly in the middle. However, the delete link is not aligned in the middle. How can I get all of them to align vertically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css?rq=1

Comment: @daOnlyBG its not a duplicate of that. I _have_ applied the vertical-align middle style to the image. but the anchor link remains aligned to the top

Comment: li p a, li p p, li p a img{vertical-align:middle;}