# Text pushed down after inserting images - need to vertically align text

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/nick55555/7tfca64y/

I probably have a situation very easy to solve but cant work out how to do it. I have a simple `div` with some text inside, which was vertically in the centre, but when I inserted an image into the same `div`, the text is now lower than it was originally. How can I make the text the same vertical height as it was before i inserted the images? the images are vertically aligned perfectly but the text isn't...

```css
  #header_Bi {
    height: 39px;
    width: 748px;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #191919;
    border-right: 1px solid #191919;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #191919;
    font-family: arial, verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #2c2c2c;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #header_Bi1 {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="header_Bi">
  <div id="header_Bi1">
    <img src="../images/youtube_tiny.jpg" width="20" height="20" alt="youtube_tiny">
    <img src="../images/twitter_tiny.jpg" width="20" height="20" alt="twitter_tiny">
    <img src="../images/facebook_tiny.jpg" width="20" height="20" alt="facebook_tiny">
    <img src="../images/google_plus_tiny.jpg" width="20" height="20" alt="google_plus_tiny">SALES &amp; ADVICE EMAIL HERE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide working code

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle for better responses.

Comment: The images come before the text so of course it will be pushed down. Your desired result sounds like the text will be on top of the image, if you truly want everything centered vertically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically align text next to an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nick55555/7tfca64y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to align the text in the middle with the images, add `#header_Bi1 img { vertical-align:middle;}` to your css