# vertical-align image + bottom text

Tags: html, css

My template :

```
<td class="image">
    <img src="">
    <div class="align-bottom">
        text
    </div>
</td>
<td class="image">
    <img src="">
    <div class="align-bottom">
        text
    </div>
</td>
<td class="image">
    <img src="">
    <div class="align-bottom">
        text
    </div>
</td>
```

How do I vertical-middle align the image (the images have different sizes...) and vertical-bottom align the text(**different sizes**.)

The `td` height is dynamic.

I'm sorry but `position:absolute` doesn't work ...**the images have different sizes**.

Comment: What you have asked for is a bit vague. Can you add a picture of what you want this to look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically align text next to an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x881rupq/9/

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to have 2 rows in the table.
Row 1 with all the images and Row 2 with the text

for each image add

```
img {    
  margin:auto;
}
```

and for text, align:center.

I think that should do the job.

Use this structure : http://jsfiddle.net/vse8cq5y/

Comment: Just made an edit to make your solution a little bit more understandable for OP.   http://jsfiddle.net/vse8cq5y/1/

Comment: Use property text-align, instead of align. for <p> in the fiddle.(my bad, missed it the first time)

Answer (score 1):

From your given HTML and request I'm assuming this is what you will need to get what you want.

The images should automatically do what you are asking, all you need to do is position absolute the text to the bottom of the td.

By adding padding bottom to the each td, you are allowing space for the text to go, meaning that it will never overlap with your image (regardless of image size).

```css
img {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  width:5em;
  height:2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td {
  width:10em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle; /*should be default*/
}
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  display:inline-block;
}

.align-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="image">
        <img src="" style="height: 4em">
        <div class="align-bottom">
            text
        </div>
</td>
    <td class="image">
        <img src="" style="height: 7em">
        <div class="align-bottom">
            text
        </div>
</td>
<td class="image">
        <img src="" style="height: 10em">
        <div class="align-bottom">
            text
        </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If the text is a lot of it will be in the picture

Comment: Either set your text to have a background color, however this will cut your image off. Another option will be to check for the height of your text, then supply this value to the padding-bottom of each td (this will need to be done using JavaScript or jQuery).