Is there a Shiny function to display a geom point shape palette?
I'm working on my first R Shiny application, specifically for customizable graph outputs. I'm looking for an input function similar to colourInput() from the colourpicker package, but which will visually display all (or just a selection) of the possible ggplot geom point shape types for the user to choose from in the UI, to be used as an input value in the server.
Does something like this exist?
Right now all I have is a list of numbers corresponding to the possible choices. It works, but it would be a lot nicer to have the shapes displayed directly in the input selection.
Thanks!!

None that I know of, but you could likely add something to selectizeInput. Also, see https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/selectizeWithIcons.html  and https://stackoverflow.com/q/46635054/3358272

Thanks! The shinyWidgets package looks promising
