# How to vertical align text next to image with skeleton grid

Tags: html, css, image, grid, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically align the images with the text on the "Board of Advisors" tab on [THIS PAGE](http://www.swordandplough.com/pages/about-us).

[image: Board of Advisors Page]

Shortened html:

```
<div class="four columns alpha"><img class="ImageBorder" src="LINK" alt="" /></div>
<div class="twelve columns omega">
<p class="padding">TEXT</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I've tried some of the multiple line solutions presented [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image), but can't get the text/image to line up correctly. Is there a good way to do this with a grid system?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to put a screenshots from the problem and code sample as well, because like this if you solved your issue in the future your question will not be relevant any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you need to add:

```
.omega{
   display: inline-block;
   float: none;
   margin-left: 0;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.alpha{
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[image]