# Align image with text

Tags: html, css

I've been running into an issue trying to vertically center an image and text together. I cannot get the image to align with the text, and even when I think it is centered, changing the browser size ruins it.

```css
.icon-button-with-text-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #7e898a;
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.icon-button-with-text-wrapper img {
    margin-right: 10px;
    max-height: 50px;
    max-width: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;

}

p {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-button-with-text-wrapper"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://i.imgur.com/YjcaGSx.png" width="100" height="100" style="
    padding-top: 10p;
" align="middle"><p>Speak to an Admissions Counselor<p></div>
```

I've tried `vertical-align: middle`, `display: table-cell` (and others), and different positions, along with adjusting the height, margins, etc. I've also looked at several other similar questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div?rq=1). However, none of those offered a solution that worked in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe so?

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

.icon-button-with-text-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #7e898a;
    background-color: white;   
    display: table;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.icon-button-with-text-wrapper > .item{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;    
}
.icon-button-with-text-wrapper > .item:nth-of-type(1){
    width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
.icon-button-with-text-wrapper img {   
    max-height: 50px;
    max-width: 50px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-button-with-text-wrapper">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YjcaGSx.png" alt="" />
     </div>
     <div class="item">  
        <p>Speak to an Admissions Counselor<p>
      </div>
 </div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/no8221L5/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flaticon WebFont</title>

        <style>
            .icon-button-with-text-wrapper {
                border: 1px solid #444;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 10px;
                font-size: 1.0em;
                vertical-align: middle;
                font-size: 1.3em;
            }
            .icon-button-with-text-wrapper img {
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                float: left;
                vertical-align: middle;
                padding: 10px;
            }
        </style>


    </head>

    <body>


        <div class="icon-button-with-text-wrapper">
            <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://i.imgur.com/YjcaGSx.png">
            <p>Speak to an Admissions Counselor<p>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works, however the image does not stay centered with the text as the size of the box changes due to the window size. http://i.imgur.com/KFVn2Tj.png

Comment: you just need to adjust padding of the image then. just put padding-top: (value which fixing the image)px;

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to float the image or put the text in its own block (p).

```css
.icon-button-with-text-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #7e898a;
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.icon-button-with-text-wrapper img {
    margin-right: 10px;
    max-height: 50px;
    max-width: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

```html
<div class="icon-button-with-text-wrapper"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://i.imgur.com/YjcaGSx.png" width="100" height="100">Speak to an Admissions Counselor</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not stay centered as the browser window changes. The image still stays in its place. http://i.imgur.com/Hq9B8Q7.png