# Vertical align text alongside SVG icon

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to align SVG icons alongside text. I've read lot of sources on how to do it, using `vertical-align: middle` being the best option for it.

I've also been able to do it, but there is one problem that I want answers to.

All the resources that I've seen, tell you to put `vertical-align: middle` only on the `img` element. E.g.

http://codepen.io/johnasp/pen/bqadn/
[Vertically align text next to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image)

But in my particular case, I need to put `vertical-align: middle` on both the `svg` and the `span` element. The difference is very subtle. But it is there.

Here's the fiddle:

```css
html, body {
    font-size: 32px;
}

.icon {
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
    vertical-align: middle; // Try commenting this line
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <svg viewBox='0 0 16 16' class="icon" >
      <path d="M7.5 1c-4.142 0-7.5 3.358-7.5 7.5s3.358 7.5 7.5 7.5c4.142 0 7.5-3.358 7.5-7.5s-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5zM7.5 14.5c-3.314 0-6-2.686-6-6s2.686-6 6-6c3.314 0 6 2.686 6 6s-2.686 6-6 6zM8 8v-2h2v-1h-2v-1h-1v1h-2v4h2v2h-2v1h2v1h1v-1h2l-0-4h-2zM7 8h-1v-2h1v2zM9 11h-1v-2h1v2z">
      </path>
    </svg>
    <span>3.4Km</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Try commenting the line which is giving vertical alignment to `span` tag, and see that the text would shift upwards.

Can someone tell me why I need to vertical align both my `svg` and `span` tags and not just the `svg` as is working everywhere else?

Comment: Why whould 2 separate elements get aligned the same way, when you put vertical-align one ine of them

Comment: Removing the `span` doesn't help as well. I've deliberately put `span` to give style to the text. Look at the answer I've linked. There it is happening

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main reason you were having problems was because your icon isn't sitting centrally in your SVG viewBox.

Your viewBox is `"0 0 16 16"` but if you check it, the icon actually occupies `"0 1 15 15"`.  If you update the viewBox, it sits better on the line without having to vertically align your `<span>`.

```css
html, body {
    font-size: 32px;
}

.icon {
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <svg viewBox='0 1 15 15' class="icon" id="foo">
      <path d="M7.5 1c-4.142 0-7.5 3.358-7.5 7.5s3.358 7.5 7.5 7.5c4.142 0 7.5-3.358 7.5-7.5s-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5zM7.5 14.5c-3.314 0-6-2.686-6-6s2.686-6 6-6c3.314 0 6 2.686 6 6s-2.686 6-6 6zM8 8v-2h2v-1h-2v-1h-1v1h-2v4h2v2h-2v1h2v1h1v-1h2l-0-4h-2zM7 8h-1v-2h1v2zM9 11h-1v-2h1v2z">
      </path>
    </svg>
    <span>3.4Km</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I actually copied the icon from "icomoon" website. Didn't know how to debug these issues (Although I was wondering why is there space on the top of circle). Thanks for this info!. I guess I'll have to learn `SVG`

Comment: The icon you are using is declared as a 16x16 unit icon.  However the graphic occupies only a 15x15 section in the top left of that 16x16 square.

Comment: Add a similar case, add the `vertical-align: middle;` rule to the `<svg>` solve it