# CSS align text and img

Tags: html, css

I am not sure how to describe it - I want to make comments looking like facebook ones:
[image]

But I am not sure how to align text like this - any suggestions?

Comment: You can do this with overflow:hidden. The solution can be found here: http://pmob.co.uk/pob/caption-clear.htm

Comment: It did the trick! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
div{width: 200px;}
img{vertical-align: top;}
img, div{display: inline-block}
```

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cvnrwo13/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vertical-align: top` to make the text aligned at the top with the image.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3juwntx/)

HTML:

```
<img src="image.png">
<div class="text">Whatever text you want here.</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Vertically align text next to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image)
This is how you align text next to an image

```
<div>
<img style="vertical-align:middle" src="<imageUrl>">
<span style="">Your text</span>
</div>
```