# How to center image while also aligning text to the right of image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align an image in the center of the page while also aligning some text to the right of the image. How would I do this in either css or html?

Here is my current attempt at this:

```css
.center-img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.center-txt {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="center-img"/>
<div class="center-txt">
  <h1>Home</h1>
</div>
```

Right now the image is not centered and the text is not centered vertically with the image

Here is a visual representation of what I would like it to look like in the end:

[image]

Comment: What are your system requirements?  IE 9+ or do you need 8, 7 or (God forbid) 6 support?

Comment: Sorry about the lack of info. I edited the post above. I couldn't find a place holder image originally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You can use a **`div`** to wrap the image and the text in and use **`text-align: center`** along with **`vertical-align: middle`**.

```css
.center-img,
.center-txt {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="center-img" />
  <div class="center-txt">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Solution 2:**

Alternatively, you can use a **`div`** to wrap the image and the text in and use **`flexbox`**. Use **`justify-content`** to center your elements horizontally and **`align-items: center`** to align them vertically.

```css
.center-img,
.center-txt {
  display: inline-block;
}
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="center-img" />
  <div class="center-txt">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Now to center the above **`wrapper`** to the middle of the screen you can use:

```
#wrapper {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**Example:**

```css
.center-img,
.center-txt {
  display: inline-block;
}
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="center-img" />
  <div class="center-txt">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did have a quick follow up though. how would you change the code to add some left padding to the text while still keeping the picture in the same spot?

Comment: You can use **`.center-txt { margin-left: 20px }`**. If you want to put some space between the image and the text use **`margin`**, not **`padding`**. Using **`padding`** will still keep them right next to each other and push the child (**`h1`** in your case) to the direction you set it. Using either will produce the same result visually, but try enabling the border on everything to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

We have a wrapper - `div`. `Div` have size 100% width and height of viewport. I give background to `div` pics and linear-gradient for darken. `Div` is a flex-block. Inner content aligned to center with `justify-content` (horizontal) and `align-items` (vertical). Its all.

ps: Sorry, sorry. Not its all. We go to drink a beer with this ladies. :)))

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 100%), url("http://beerhold.it/600/400");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}
img {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://beerhold.it/100/100">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not useful.  Explain what you've done, and why / how it works.  This is a correct answer, and if you edit it to explain what you are doing and why it works, I'll upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="img.jpg"/>
    <div class="text">
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container{
    text-align:center;
}

img, .text{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not useful.  Explain what you've done, and why / how it works.

Comment: @cale_b fair enough, will do in future :)

Answer (score 0):

To center the image use

```
 img.center{
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a little explanation?

Answer (score 0):

wrap both image and text inside a container and add `display:flex` to it.

then, to center them use `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;`

see below snippet. let me know if it works for you

*for more info about how to center vertically see here -> [Vertical Centering with Flexbox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/)*

```css
.center-img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.center-txt {
    display: inline-block;
}
.container { 
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  border:2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;padding:0 15px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">


<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="center-img"/>
<div class="center-txt">
  <h1>Home</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `vertical-align: middle;` to class `center-img`

The vertical-align property sets the vertical alignment of an element.
Using middle place it in the middle of the parent element

```css
.center-img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.center-txt {
    display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="center-img"/>
<div class="center-txt">
  <h1>Home</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this-

```
<div>
<img style="vertical-align:middle" src="https://placehold.it/60x60">
<span style="">Right Vertical aligned text</span>
</div>
```

[Refer to this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image)

Answer (score -1):

Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jn4rktaa/

HTML:

```
<div class="outside">
   <div class="inside">
      <img src='/img/file.jpg' class="img" />
      Test Text
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outside {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.inside {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: calc(50% - 100px); /* THE VALUE (100PX) SHOULD BE HALF OF YOUR ELEMENT'S HEIGHT */
}

.img {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: He didn't ask that. He said "aligning some text to the right of the image". I figured the text was shown centered vertically just to display an example, not a strict requirement.

Comment: Hi, please refer this below fiddle, this is simple CSS that can work on all browsers. 

https://jsfiddle.net/jn4rktaa/2/