# Vertically align center inside a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make 3 contents appear vertically center inside a div. I used `vertical-align:middle` but it does not do what i want to do. How can I fix this?

I want the `home_post_time` to appear at the right corner vertically centered.I've tried `float:right;` but could not do what i wanted. This is how i want it to appear

```
Image
Image    text                time
Image
```

```css
.home_post_sections {
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  background-color: #01ff70;
  text-align: left;
}

.home_post_propic {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.home_post_username {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.home_post_time {
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div className="home_post_sections">

  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-55-55-9.jpg" className="home_post_propic" />
  <a className="home_post_username">User name</a>
  <a className="home_post_time">23h</a>

</div>
```

Comment: @ManojLodhi No - Create a snippet here! Just like I did using the `<>` button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically align text next to an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image)

Comment: Please read the extensive SO documentation on [`Vertical centering`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/5070/vertical-centering#t=201702211211393223577). Recommended method: `flexbox`.

Comment: refer this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/rqub5L9d)

Comment: Typo in the class too. Not className

Comment: Best answer regarding this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19461564/3290256

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
<div  style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
<h1>Text In center</h1>
</div>
```

for your code

```
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-55-55-9.jpg" className="home_post_propic" />
<a className="home_post_username">User name</a>
 <a className="home_post_time">23h</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use flex to make it vertical center as below

```
<style>
 .home_post_sections{
   display : flex;
   align-items : center; //make child items align vertically center
 }
</style>

<div className="home_post_sections">

  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-55-55-9.jpg" className="home_post_propic" />
  <a className="home_post_username">User name</a>
  <a className="home_post_time">23h</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made the main container position: relative;
The time container I've made position: absolute; with a top of 50% and a margin-top minus half of its height. 10px was just an approximate.

```
.home_post_sections {
    position: relative;
}
.home_post_time {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1f09hp3f/

You've used mostly static widths and heights so this solution should work for you, if you only want to center align one element. Otherwise you can have a look at the below link to center align all elements vertically.
[Vertical alignment of elements in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)