# How to centralize an icon and a paragraph in one line

Tags: html, css, reactjs, icons

I'm trying to centralize an icon and a paragraph in the header of application. Currently it looks like this.

[image]

I want to show an icon and a paragraph with same height. I added `padding-bottom`to make it happen though it didn't work.

sample.js (The application is made with React.js )

```
<div className="title"><img src={title} className="title" alt="title" />SAMPLE TITLE</div>
```

index.css

```
.title {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #454545;
color: white;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Edit :
This question was marked as duplicate with [Vertically align text next to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image). I didn't know about `vertical align` and I think there is people like me, so I would like to keep this question.

Comment: Try applying the same `line-height` to both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `display` and `vertical-align` property on `img`

```css
.title {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #454545;
  color: white;
}

.title img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="title"><img src='https://placehold.it/40x40' alt="title" />SAMPLE TITLE</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly.

Comment: No need to have `inline-block` in this case.

Comment: @Chris good point, your answer is cleaner

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will remove it.  I needed to specify ```img``` together with className so I chose this one as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since your image is displayed `inline` that's what you want to align, not the text. Just use the `vertical-align: middle` property. Take a look at the description over at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align):

> The **vertical-align** CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an inline or table-cell box.

```js
const MyApp = () => <div className="title">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" className="title" alt="title" /> SAMPLE TITLE
</div>;
 
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
.title {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #454545;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use flex css

```
.title {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 align-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.title img {
 margin-right: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a `line-height` to the text with the same `height` of the image.

**Example**

```
<div className="title">
  <img src={title} style={{ height: 25 }} className="title" alt="title" />
  <span style={{lineHeight: 25}}>SAMPLE TITLE</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vertical-align: middle` on the `img`.

```css
.title {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #454545;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.title img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="title"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="title" />SAMPLE TITLE</div>
```