# React icon does not align with text

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a very simple question, I have react icon and text in front of it. The text is not aligned with the React Icon. How can I align it with text? Check the screenshot. My code is:

```
<MdPerson size={20}/><span> Profile</span>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQvWM.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically align text next to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image)

Comment: I have tried that and its not working :(

Comment: Apply line height and height to profile span which is equal to image height and then apply vertical align

Answer (score 17):

Try to wrap icon component and your `span` label with outer `div` block. Then apply some class to the div where child elements aligned by flexbox.

```
.centered-label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Andriis answer of wrapping it in a flex box combined with the answer from [this github issue thread](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons/issues/222) worked for me.

`vertical-align: bottom;` style on the icon.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Andrii, wrap your Icon component & `span` label in a parent `div` style the div as below:

```
<div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "center"}}>
<MdPerson size={20}/><span> Profile</span>
</div>
```

Worked for me perfectly!