# Vertically align image in table

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a "Why Choose Us" splash page and I want to create tables with an image on one side and a reason on the other. I need the image to vertically align in the center.

So far I've tried making another table inside the table, and vertically aligning the image with 'vertical-align: middle' via a table cell wrapped around it.

```
<section class="reason">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="float-left table">
                <div class="table-cell">
                    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://1eican1u2cuw7g1kw7btt2xy-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/personal-attention-vamospanish-85x85.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <h3>
                    Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
                </h3>
                <p class="appeal">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

<style>
.reason {
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.content {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  max-width: 935px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.float-left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}

.table {
  display: table;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.thumbnail {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

Here's a codepen outlining the problem: https://codepen.io/AlecAcres/pen/NVMRoY

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically align text next to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

May be a style to `<td>`?

```
<style>
td img { 
  vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code (basically used `flex` instead of `table`) -:
[Working demo here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WBJovg)

HTML

```
<section class="reason">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="float-left">
            <div class="table-cell">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="https://1eican1u2cuw7g1kw7btt2xy-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/personal-attention-vamospanish-85x85.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="float-right">
            <h3>
                            Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
                    </h3>
            <p class="appeal">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.reason {
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 935px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.float-left {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.float-right {
  flex: 1
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.thumbnail {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-image {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```
 <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-image">
      <img
        src="https://1eican1u2cuw7g1kw7btt2xy-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/personal-attention-vamospanish-85x85.png">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-content">
      <h3>
        Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
      </h3>
      <p class="appeal">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more modern approach using FlexBox!

Demo: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WBJoxY

HTML:

```
<section class="reason">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://1eican1u2cuw7g1kw7btt2xy-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/personal-attention-vamospanish-85x85.png">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h3>
        Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
      </h3>
      <p class="appeal">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.reason {
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 935px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.text {
  max-width: 50%;
}

.thumbnail {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```