# how do I align text inside a header with images html?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my images with the text so its in the middle in a line.

```
<div id="bar">
      <h2><img src="images/java.png" alt="logo">Java<img src="images/c++.png" alt="logo">C/C++<img src="images/unity.png" alt="logo">Unity<img src="images/sql.png" alt="logo">SQL<img src="images/html.png" alt="logo">HTML<img src="images/css.png" alt="logo">CSS<img src="images/python.png" alt="logo">Python</h2> 
  </div>
```

```
#bar h2{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But still looks like this
[image]

Comment: Add the vertical alignment style to the images, not the `h2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertically align text next to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use flexible box model:

```
#bar h2 { 
  display: flex; 
  flex-diretion:row; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items:center;
}
```

but is a better idea to put that inside a div and then create a css class for that:

```
.languages-bar {
  display: flex; 
  flex-diretion:row; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items:center;
}
```